# How can I calculate distance between coordinates on multiple matching rows in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a sheet with 20,000 rows.  Each row has an object ID, which can occur multiple times throughout the sheet.  Each row also contains coordinates, as they are real world points. Each object can occur multiple times through the sheet because a row represents an object being found in an image. And 1 image = 1 day, hence the date attribute.

I need to query the column with object ID's, which I know how to do using INDEX:MATCH.  But I then need to calculate, for each object, the distance between successive coordinates.  I calculate the distance using this formula: d=(sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2)).  The problem I am having is how to create an Excel formula to calculate between successive matching rows.

[image: screenshot]

In the example I have highlighted the rows with object ID 30. They occur 7 times.  I would need to calculate the distance between successive entries, 30(1) vs. 30(2), 30(2) vs. 30(3), etc., so six distance calculations.
I need to do that for every object ID (excluding single-occurring object ID's)

Comment: 1) For 7 occurrences, you're talking about 21 distances?  2) What is the formula?

Comment: @fixer1234 Sorry I should clarify that multiple occurrences of an object ID is an object appearing over multiple days. So distances only need to be calculated sequentially not between every record (The distance it has moved over each day) There for there would only need to be 5 calculations for 7 records, distance between day 1 and 2, distance between day 2 and 3, etc etc.

The formula for distance between coordinates is
 d=(sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2))

Comment: (1) Since IDs occur multiple times, you should probably delete the word “unique”, or else clarify how you mean it.  (2) If you have seven records for an object, then you have ***six*** pairs of consecutive records — see [fencepost error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error).  (3) That’s funny; @fixer1234 and I live on a spherical planet — you live on a two-dimensional world?  And you have Internet access there?!  … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer.

Comment: I fixed ID and you were right about having six pairs instead of five that was my bad, updated in post. However I don't understand your little dig in your 3rd comment.

Comment: G-Man's point #3 relates to how you are calculating distance.  If the distances are short, your formula is probably close enough.  But the actual distance is along an arc because the surface is spherical.  Point-to-point would be the distance tunneling under the surface.  Worst case would be opposite sides of the planet (diameter vs. circumference).  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance.

Comment: Oh ok, I understand that. For what I am looking at the simple distance formula is fine.The coordinates are projected into a local MGA zone so the distance calculation is close enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed a minimal data layout — rows contain ID, X coordinate,
and Y coordinate in Columns `A`, `B`, and `C`, respectively. 
In Column `D`, use `MATCH` to find the next row with the same ID. 
In Columns `E` and `F`, use `INDEX` to find the X and Y coordinates
for the next occurrence of the same ID. 
In Column `G`, compute the distance between this point and the next one.

- `D2` → `=MATCH(A2, A3:A$9, 0)+ROW()`
- `E2` → `=INDEX(B:B, $D2, 1)`
- `F2` → `=INDEX(C:C, $D2, 1)`
- `G2` → `=IF(ISERROR(D2), "", SQRT((E2-B2)^2+(F2-C2)^2))`

(replacing the `9` in the formula for `D2`
with your last valid data row number) and drag/fill down.

[image]

The distance values work out to be integers
because I chose the first two Pythagorean triples (3-4-5 and 5-12-13)
for the inter-point vectors.

Comment: Thanks Scott, this worked well after a little bit of playing.